# How to choose TabBarController Selected Index when there's more than 5 tab bar items & user can reorder them?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an Xamarin.iOS app with more than 5 tab bar items. In the home screen of this app the tab bar is hidden. 
You can still navigate the app via UIButtons in the view instead of the Tab Bar.

When there was less than 5 tabBar items I could easily navigate by selecting the index on the touch of the button:

```
servicesButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
    {              
        TabBarController.SelectedIndex = 1;
    };
```

Now since I have more than 5 tab bar items and they can be reordered by the user, I can't use hard coded indices.

My current working solution is this:

```
servicesButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TabBarController.ViewControllers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (TabBarController.ViewControllers[i].Title.Equals("Services"))
            {
                TabBarController.SelectedIndex = i;
            }
        }
    };
```

This seems to work but does anybody know of a better way to go about accomplishing this task?

Comment: could you use an object with a unique ID to set the selected index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

- Set the `Tag` property on the view, e.g., services view tag set to 5
- Use LINQ to select the view controller
- Then set the `SelectedViewController` on the `TabBarController`

Like this:

```cs
servicesButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
{
    var servicesViewController = TabBarController.ViewControllers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.View.Tag == 5);
    if(servicesViewController != null)
    {
        TabBarController.SelectedViewController = servicesViewController;
    }
};
```

You can set the tag either in the storyboard/xib or programmatically.